# Vaadin 7 Session Id

Tags: java, session, vaadin, vaadin7

Does Vaadin 7 offer some kind of session identifier? I want to track some usage by each session.

I looked at the doc for [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html) but did not notice any.

I suppose I could roll my own by generating a UUID and attaching it to the VaadinSession with a call to `setAttribute`. But no need if Vaadin gives me an identifier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could get the `SESSION_ID` via the [`VaadinSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/VaadinSession.html) ( and then [`WrappedSession`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/server/WrappedSession.html)).

```
VaadinSession.getCurrent().getSession().getId()
```

Comment: Works the same in Vaadin 8.